# Overlapping bar chart with multiple axis in PowerBi

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to have a overlapping bar chart in PowerBi with multiple axis. I have an example from Excel which I would prefer to recreate in PowerBi if this is possible.

Here the example:

[image: Preferred Graph]

Is this possible in PowerBi? Maybe by using a custom visual I don't know off.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple axes? Yes! Overlapping bars? No!

Using a `Line and Clustered Column Chart` is the way to go:

[image]

---

Here's a demo using some random numbers:

```
Date        A           B           C
07.08.2018  0,359008828 0,993689927 0,8
08.08.2018  0,127630228 0,449164386 0,8
09.08.2018  0,431825126 0,615830289 0,8
10.08.2018  0,269830973 0,984995499 0,8
11.08.2018  0,27416548  0,64248379  0,8
12.08.2018  0,777712123 0,740108131 0,8
13.08.2018  0,264229043 0,242084953 0,8
14.08.2018  0,49124239  0,144428206 0,8
15.08.2018  0,242050334 0,020032871 0,8
16.08.2018  0,316102617 0,644935538 0,8
```

1. Use <kbd>Enter Data</kbd> to get a table with these numbers under <kbd>Fields</kbd>:

[image]

2. Click <kbd>Line and Clustered Column Chart</kbd> under <kbd>Visualizations</kbd>

[image]

3. Drag `Date` to `Shared Axis`, and change the date hierarchy to simple date using the drop down menu next to `Date`.

[image]

4. Drag `C` to `Line Values`, and `A` and `B` to `Column values`:

[image]

5. Under Y axis, set `Show Secondary` to `On`

[image]

And that's as close as you're going to get to replicate your Excel Chart at the time being as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not an ideal solution, but it is possible to place charts on top of each other. This is the result of two bar charts superimposed upon each other:

[image: Double Chart]

Note: In order to have control over the column width, you need to change the x-axis to categorical and adjust the inner padding.

Comment: thnx for your answer Alexis. I do prefer the solution off vastland though. Overlaping charts can causes problems in the version op PowerBi we are using here. (It glitches)

Comment: Yes, I certainly don't recommend my suggestion, but I wanted to provide another answer that more matched your requested formatting.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple custom visuals available on the appsource now. Search for lipstick charts. see screenshot below. one of those is here

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-US/product/power-bi-visuals/yavdaanalyticspvtltd1628223732998.lipstickcolumnpro?tab=Overview

[image: microsoft power bi appsource lipstick column pbivizedit]