# Can I make a Power BI Trend Chart with 3 Axis?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 values which I don't need to compare the size of them to each other, just their trending nature.  However, when I try to put them into a line chart/combo chart one value is always drowned out.

THe values are:  Summation of Spending, Percentage of Turns, and Time To Sell (in days).  So one month can have this:
Spend: 200,000
Turns:  9%
TTS:  107

This data is by month as well.

The one thing I am trying from the below article is stacking charts on each other. Which is ugly and causes me to lose some visibility on the chart in the back.

This article gets me close but not quite.
[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51721282/overlapping-bar-chart-with-multiple-axis-in-powerbi)

Comment: Perhaps normalize the values and use one/two axis?

Comment: were you thinking of something like this?  https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/09/normalize-your-measures-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Yes, those look like some techniques to normalize data, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)